# Mapper Output as Comma Separated Value

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am having CSV file as Below.I am writing mapReduce Program which calculates  product which was sold max on particular day.

[CSV Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emim6.png)

For that the output of the mapper should be of the form

1/2/09=>[Product1,Product2,Product1,Product2,Product4,.....]

I have written Mapper code as Below

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
        throws IOException {

    String line = value.toString();
    String[] arrLine = line.split(",");

    String strDateTime        = arrLine[0];     
    String strDate  = strDateTime.substring(0, strDateTime.indexOf(" ")); 
    String strProductName = arrLine[1];

    Map products = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String strProdAdded = null;

    if(products.get(strDate)!= null)
    {
        strProdAdded = products.get(strDate).toString();
        strProdAdded += strProductName + ",";
        products.put(strDate, strProdAdded);
    }else
    {
        products.put(strDate, strProductName);
    }

    output.collect(new Text(strDate), new Text(strProductName));
}
```

But I am unable to figure out the exact way to get the desired output as below

1/2/09=>[Product1,Product2,Product1,Product2,Product4,.....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to use `cleanup()` method, I have added `System.out` statements so you can understand what is going on in method. see available methods that you can use for [Mapper class here.](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html)

```
public static class StackMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        private Map<Text, ArrayList<Text>> products = new HashMap<Text, ArrayList<Text>>();
        private ArrayList<Text> p = new ArrayList<Text>();

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

               String line = value.toString();
               String[] arrLine = line.split(",");

               Text strDate  = new Text(arrLine[0].substring(0, arrLine[0].indexOf(" "))); 
               Text strProductName = new Text(arrLine[1]);

               if(products.containsKey(strDate))
                {
                    if(!products.get(strDate).contains(strProductName)) {
                        System.out.println("has date: " + strDate + " " + strProductName + " not exist, added to list: " + p.toString());
                        p.add(strProductName);
                    }  
                    System.out.println("has date: " + strDate + ", "  + strProductName + " added to list: " + p.toString());      
                }else
                {
                    p = new ArrayList<Text>();
                    p.add(strProductName);

                    System.out.println("new date: " + strDate + ", " + strProductName + " added to list: " + p.toString());  
                }

               products.put(new Text(strDate), p);   
        }  

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            for ( Text date : products.keySet()){
                context.write(date, new Text(products.get(date).toString()));
            }

        }
    }
```

***input:***

```
1/2/09 6:17,product1,f3,f4,f5
1/2/09 6:17,product2,f3,f4,f5
1/2/09 6:17,product3,f3,f4,f5
1/2/09 6:17,product4,f3,f4,f5
1/2/09 6:17,product4,f3,f4,f5
1/2/10 6:17,product1,f3,f4,f5u
1/2/10 6:17,product2,f3,f4,f5u
1/2/10 6:17,product3,f3,f4,f5u
1/2/11 6:17,product2,f3,f4,f5u
1/2/12 6:17,product2,f3,f4,f5u
1/2/12 6:17,product3,f3,f4,f5u
```

---

***output:***

```
1/2/09  [product1, product2, product3, product4]
1/2/10  [product1, product2, product3]
1/2/12  [product2, product3]
1/2/11  [product2]
```

---

***MR job's std output:***

```
new date: 1/2/09, product1 added to list: [product1]
has date: 1/2/09 product2 not exist, added to list: [product1]
has date: 1/2/09, product2 added to list: [product1, product2]
has date: 1/2/09 product3 not exist, added to list: [product1, product2]
has date: 1/2/09, product3 added to list: [product1, product2, product3]
has date: 1/2/09 product4 not exist, added to list: [product1, product2, product3]
has date: 1/2/09, product4 added to list: [product1, product2, product3, product4]
has date: 1/2/09, product4 added to list: [product1, product2, product3, product4]
new date: 1/2/10, product1 added to list: [product1]
has date: 1/2/10 product2 not exist, added to list: [product1]
has date: 1/2/10, product2 added to list: [product1, product2]
has date: 1/2/10 product3 not exist, added to list: [product1, product2]
has date: 1/2/10, product3 added to list: [product1, product2, product3]
new date: 1/2/11, product2 added to list: [product2]
new date: 1/2/12, product2 added to list: [product2]
has date: 1/2/12 product3 not exist, added to list: [product2]
has date: 1/2/12, product3 added to list: [product2, product3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the Effort @BigDataLearner. Your solution took me close to my Requirement

Answer (score 0):

The output that you are expecting, in my opinion, could be the result of a Reduce job. This is essentially a GroupBy date query implementation and as far as I understand it is handled by reduce job. 
Per your program, I guess you are outputting right Key and values out of your map job. Once they are sorted, shuffled and passed on to the reducer you will be able to see all products for a particular date grouped together.

*P.S. Given a chance I would use Pig or Hive to address this unless you are doing this as a exercise to try your hands on Map-Reduce.*